# iOS Design: Is a search button better placed in navigation bar or in its own tab?

Tags: ios, user-experience

I have an app and a feature is where people can search by tags and a big problem I am having is whether I should put the search button in its own tab or in the navigation bar right side.

Setup is currently a tab bar with the feed, browse, and profile tabs. I would either be adding a 4th tab for search, or place it in the right side of the navigation bar of each tab. Can I get pros and cons of each of these options to consider?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a UX question.
Ask on the appropriate SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider search a core functionality of your app, equal to the levels of your feed, browse, and profile, then I would place it in the tab bar.

If search is meant to behave differently on your feed, browse, and profile pages, I would place it in the nav bar.

I hope this helps; its difficult to make a judgement like this because there is no right answer.